# Adding GeoServer layer to Mapbox?

Tags: geoserver, mapbox

I've published some layers in GeoServer which I want to consume in Mapbox.
I've tried several examples like:

- [Add simple image layers to MapBox / Leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82950/add-simple-image-layers-to-mapbox-leaflet)
- [Mapbox Vector Tiles from Geoserver 2.11 in Mapbox GL JS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238301/mapbox-vector-tiles-from-geoserver-2-11-in-mapbox-gl-js/240568)
- [Mapbox Docs | Add a vector tile source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/vector-source/)

But I'm not been able to get any good result, I've got this as the best result till now

[image: example] using the code

```js
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'wms-test-layer',
    'type': 'raster',
    'source': {
        'type': 'raster',
        'tiles': [
            'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo/topp:states?gridSet=EPSG:4326&format=image/png'

        ],
        'tileSize': 256
    },
    'paint': {}
}, 'aeroway-line');
```

What can I do?

Comment: is your map in epsg:4326? if not then you might want a different grid set

Comment: why not use wms layer as geoserver can provide wms service?

Comment: @neogeomat yes I tried publishing and consuming as WMS layer but no luck

Comment: @IanTurton my Layer and Map both are 4326

Answer (score 1):

why not use wms layer as geoserver can provide wms service

```
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?', {
    layers: 'topp:states'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.I want to load in Mapbox GL JS